# How to program macro to compare column in two Excel worksheets and add matches to third sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked and attempted to fit whatever code I have run across on this site (since this morning) into a working application with non-functional or poor results.

I need to be able to match if id numbers in the "A" column of sheet 1 match in the respective "A" column of sheet 2, and just paste the matches to column "A" in sheet 3.  The column range in sheet 1 is not the same range as sheet 2, and sheet 3 needs to have the matches pasted in each row as they are found (i.e. no blank rows in between).  I do not need to do anything about numbers that do not match.

I have attempted to modify code from a different thread; it catches some matches, but not all.  I guess the ranges are incorrect but I don't really know how to code that in VBA.  Plus there are spaces in the column where some of the other duplicates should be posted.  The "if found is nothing then x = 0" is unnecessary (and may even be causing the aforementioned error), but if I take that out I get a type mismatch error.

```
Sub matchPAs()

Dim x, i, total, fRow As Integer
Dim found As Range

total = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To total
    match1 = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value
 Set found = Sheets(2).Columns("A:A").Find(what:=match1)
If found Is Nothing Then
    x = 0
Else
    fRow = Sheets(2).Columns("A:A").Find(what:=match1).Row
    Worksheets(3).Range("A" & i).Value = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & fRow).Value

 End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If you review the `Related` heading on the right side of this page you will see multiple questions w/ answers, you might want to review them.

Comment: "it catches some matches, but not all" - it sounds like you have mostly solved it. I would guess that the failed matches are whitespace differences. Have you tried trimming both strings in the comparison?